# How to run NSTimer in background and sleep in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I found a lot of post in stackoverflow about `NSTimer` run in background.

However I didn't find any solution.

In my app , I play sound in background and I set timer to stop music when it reached that time.

So I need to run my `NSTimer` background (mean when home button click and sleep iPhone).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 30):

```
// NSTimer run when app in background <br>

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
loop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(Update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:loop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

This is what do you want?.

Comment: how long will this run for?

Comment: @Flimzy, How long this will run in background mode? I am testing with this code & it's about 20+ minutes and still going on. Sounds good. :D
But before implementing it in real project I have to confirm myself. :(

Comment: @Tulon: I have no idea. It's not my code. I just re-formatted the answer.

Comment: Solved my problem ! Thanks a lot +100

Comment: @Flimzy  - I have requirement to fire the timer after 30 mins in background. Will the above logic works for 30 mins?

Comment: @vijay As I already said: I have no idea. It's not my code. I just reformatted the answer.

Comment: @Vijay I think you should try "silent push notification", It is works for me.

Answer (score 3):

### You can’t

Timers only exist within your application. So (except for a very small window) when your app is sent to the background, timers cannot fire anymore.

(The audio keeps running, because it’s played by the *system*, and not by your app.)

So you cannot use timers for this purpose.

What you can do — as suggested by iPatel — is use a local notification, instead. This will briefly awake your app, allowing you to stop playing the music.

Comment: So where should i write my stop playing music in his method?

Answer (score 2):

Get Form [This Question] (http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/58643-keep-nstimer-running-when-app-is-in-background-multitasking.html)

```
- (void)btnSetupNotificationClicked:(id)sender
{
    UILocalNotification* pOrderCompletedNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if(pOrderCompletedNotification!=nil)
    {
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setFireDate:[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.00]];
//      [pOrderCompletedNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setSoundName:@\"OrderCompleted.m4a\"];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setAlertBody:@\"Order Completed\"];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setAlertAction:nil];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setHasAction:NO];

        UIApplication* pApplication=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if(pApplication!=nil)
        {
            [pApplication scheduleLocalNotification:pOrderCompletedNotification];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@\"Application singleton allocation error.\");
        }

        [pOrderCompletedNotification release];
        [pApplication release];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@\"Local notification creation error.\");
    }   // if
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Swift

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
app.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(nil)
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
            target: self,
            selector:"DoSomethingFunctions",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is relatively old but I recently ran into this problem and was having some trouble figuring it out.  This is the solution I came up with as of Swift 5.  It uses a combination of the RunLoop and Timer classes, with information about them in the provided links below.

Using timers

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer

Using run loops

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop

Sample code:

```swift
class AMSleepTimerUtil: NSObject {
    static let shared = AMSleepTimerUtil()
    fileprivate var sleepTimer: Timer?
    
    /// Initialize the timer to trigger a function to execute after a duration of time
    /// - Parameter seconds: the time delay until the selector function executes
    /// - Returns: true if sleep timer were successfully initialized
    func createTimerToStopMusic(at seconds: TimeInterval) -> Bool {
        let fireAtDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: seconds)
        stopSleepTimer()
        
        self.sleepTimer = Timer(fireAt: fireAtDate,
                                interval: 0,
                                target: self,
                                selector: #selector(pauseMusic),
                                userInfo: nil,
                                repeats: false)
        guard let sleepTimer = sleepTimer else { return false }
        RunLoop.main.add(sleepTimer, forMode: .common)
        
        return true
    }
    
    func pauseMusic() {
        guard let audioPlayer = AMNowPlayingViewController.sharedInstance()?.audioPlayer else { return }
        
        audioPlayer.pause()
    }
    
    /// Used to reset the sleep timer before initializing a new timer if the user clicks the "Set Timer" multiple times
    func stopSleepTimer() {
        if sleepTimer != nil {
            sleepTimer?.invalidate()
            sleepTimer = nil
        }
    }
    
    func sleepTimerIsActive() -> Bool {
        return self.sleepTimer != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you run `NSTimer`, the `@selector` method itself will determine wether you want to run in background or main thread.

**Initial set up:**

```
self.scanTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(manageMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *scanTimer
```

**Case you want to run in Background:**

```
-(void)manageMethod
{
      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mysite.thread1",NULL);
      dispatch_async(queue,^{ 
           //run in background
      });
}
```

Comment: I think juster is asking about if his app goes in the background, not using a background thread.