# UILocalNotification background event fire to pause Music in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

i need to pause playing music when UILocalNotification event fire.

Someone suggest me to do with following codes.

You can see my post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092016/how-to-run-nstimer-in-background-and-sleep-in-ios)

Here is codes

```
- (void)btnSetupNotificationClicked:(id)sender
{
    UILocalNotification* pOrderCompletedNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if(pOrderCompletedNotification!=nil)
    {
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setFireDate:[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.00]];
//      [pOrderCompletedNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setSoundName:@"OrderCompleted.m4a"];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setAlertBody:@"Order Completed"];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setAlertAction:nil];
        [pOrderCompletedNotification setHasAction:NO];

        UIApplication* pApplication=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if(pApplication!=nil)
        {
            [pApplication scheduleLocalNotification:pOrderCompletedNotification];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Application singleton allocation error.");
        }

        [pOrderCompletedNotification release];
        [pApplication release];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Local notification creation error.");
    }   // if
}
```

But i don't know where should i write my `self.player pause` code in these method?
Do i need to connect with following code in AppDelegate?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"EVENT from Notification");
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your player object **should be declare in your AppDelegate** file so that when notification fire your can use self.player object and you can pause your music

Comment: i want to know when notification event fire , which event i need to Implement for my player to pause?

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"EVENT from Notification");
}

Comment: @juster this event will fire when your Notification fire with alert and from the alert when you press button to continue/ ope your app at that time this event will be fire .

Comment: i want to pause automatically when noti alert without press button to open my app.

Comment: That's can be because iDownloader App's Music SleepTimer feature is like that

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you should do the required coding in method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

which gets called whenever the user receives the notification. No event gets fired when the device receives the notification. This is the only event which gets fired when you open the received notification.